# Selection from a dropdown returns the key instead of the value

Tags: jquery, html

I am populating a dropdown using jQuery. However, when I select a value from the dropdown that has been populated the key is returned.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-select-group">
    <label for="selectRegion">Select Region:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectRegion" name="selectRegion">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select your State first</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectState').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "RegionView",
      cache: false,
      data: $(selectState).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
      }
    }).done(function(responseJson) {
      dataType: "json",
      // Clear options
      $("#selectRegion").find("option").remove();
      $('#selectRegion').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your Region</option>'));
      $("#selectDistrict").find("option").remove();
      $('#selectDistrict').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your Region first</option>'));
      $("#selectGroup").find("option").remove();
      $("#selectSection").find("option").remove();
      $("#selectSubSection").find("option").remove();
      // Loop through JSON response
      $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {  $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#selectRegion"));
      });
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectRegion').on('change', function() {
    //do something here
    //alert($("#accountName").val());
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "DistrictView",
      cache: false,
      data: $(selectRegion).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
      }
    }).done(function(responseJson) {
      dataType: "json",
      // Clear options
      $("#selectDistrict").find("option").remove();
      $('#selectDistrict').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your District</option>'));
      $("#selectGroup").find("option").remove();
      $('#selectGroup').append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your District first</option>'));
      $("#selectSection").find("option").remove();
      $("#selectSubSection").find("option").remove();
      // Loop through JSON response
      $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {  $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#selectDistrict"));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The first function receives a "State" and passes it to the java to get the list of "Regions" associated with the "State". This list of "Regions" is displayed as a dropdown. When I select a "Region" I want to return a list of "Districts" to display in the next dropdown. However, if I select the fifth option (Sydney North) the key (4) is returned to the java instead of "Sydney North". How do I get the value instead of the key?

The Java that receives the Region is:

```
@WebServlet("/DistrictView")
public class DistrictView extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String region = request.getParameter("selectRegion"); // From bootstrap
    response.getWriter().write("Region = " + region);
    MySQLConnection.getConnection();
    List < String > listDistricts = MySQLConnection.listGroupDistricts(region);
    if (listDistricts == null || listDistricts.isEmpty()) {
      response.getWriter().write("No Districts in this Region.");
    } else {
      String json = new Gson().toJson(listDistricts);
      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
      response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
  }
}
```

When I use the following to populate the dropdown:

```
$.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
  $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#selectRegion"));
});
```

The `response.getWriter().write("Region = " + region);` returns "Region = 4". I am expecting "Sydney North" to be passed (which is what I selected).

When I replace this with:

```
$.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
  $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo($("#selectRegion"));
});
```

Then the `response.getWriter().write("Region = " + region);` does not return anything.

I am expecting to have the temporary display "response.getWriter().write("Region = " + region);" to display the actual value I selected (not the key) the java will then use this value to query the database and return a list of Districts which will be populated to the next dropdown by the `$('#selectRegion').on('change', function() {` code.

I have tried this:

```
var selectedText = $("#selectRegion").find("option:selected").text();
    alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DistrictView",
        cache: false,
        data: $(selectedText).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
        }
    })
```

The alert shows "Selected Text: Sydney North". However, the java display shows that "data: $(selectedText).serialize()," is passing "null" to the java WebServlet.

Comment: I have added further I formation about attempted resolutions. This did not work and I am continuing to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
// Loop through JSON response
$.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {  
    $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#selectRegion"));
});
```

with:

```
$.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
    $('<option>').text(value).appendTo($("#selectRegion"));
});
```

And, in the java, replace:

```
String region = request.getParameter("selectRegion"); // From bootstrap
```

with:

```
String[] region = request.getParameterValues("selectRegion"); // From bootstrap
String region0 = region[0];
```

and replace all further references to "region" with "region0".